# What causes these spikes in an LTspice circuit analysis of a full adder?

Tags: transistors, ltspice

For the following full adder circuit:

[image]

I get the following output for s (I have the same problem with COUT):

[image]

The graph itself is correct, but those spikes should not be there. I know that I have to change the sine wave somehow but I can't figure it out. How do I avoid getting those spikes?

Comment: With the delays inherently present in this circuit, you can't have a "good" behavior ... You should go faster with the input signals.

Comment: What happens if you change your rise/fall times from 5n to 5p?

Comment: [If I use ideal gates and change the rise/fall time to 5p, then I get no glitches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1Jc5.png).  But I think a worthwhile takeaway from the exercise is that when built in real life, this circuit is glitchy no matter what and you need to "register" your outputs like the accepted answer suggests you must do.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These spikes are called "glitches", which occur when signals propagate through combinatorial logic because the gates aren't infinitely fast. As a result, the circuit goes through intermediate states which might temporarily cause incorrect outputs.

This is completely expected and not an error in your circuit or the simulation. The circuit just needs a tiny bit of time until it has calculated the correct result.

Your circuit works perfectly fine.

If you really want the spikes to be gone, you need to make the circuit synchronous by adding input and output registers, as well as a clock signal to drive them. This is likely overkill for such a simple experiment.

Comment: Propagation delays can be emulated by adding some (small) capacitors to the circuit. These would help reduce glitches, but also impact the rise and fall time of the output pulse.

Comment: https://www.vlsisystemdesign.com/propagation-delay-of-cmos-inverter/#:~:text=Rise%20time%20(tr)%20is,to%2030%25%20for%20fall%20time